# Ubuntu intaller crashes every times

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** on a FreeDOS HP laptop (i7700hq 8Goram GTX1050ti).

I tried **Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.8.4** and  **unetbootin-windows-661** (respectively https://www.pendrivelinux.com/ and https://unetbootin.github.io/) to make the USB key bootable.

I went to the laptop bios and activate the USB key boot option. I plug the key in and the key boots. I can chose to try or install Ubuntu.

In both of the choices it crashes during the loading and I cannot use keyboard or mouse. I tried to change Bios options but nothing.

Any links ideas or solutions?

Note: FreeDOS is installed on it.

Comment: FreeDOS is installed on it.

Comment: You might check the ISO for corruption using MD5SUM or try the USB on a second computer, UNetbootin, (Linux), has been having some problems with 18.04.

Comment: Hey @MaximeOBLE it would be useful to post the image of the error, please take your phone and make the screen photo so we can at least see the error you're experiencing.

Comment: hey, thanks for you answer. I tryied with rufus following the ubuntu doc and installation guide but I got the same isue. @janmyszkier I have no error message, that is why I dont find answers. When the ubuntu name apear with 5 white dots,like loading screen before installation begins, they go one by one orange, then white again but at one moment it freezes (every time at the same moment) and i dont have any error message (or dont know if I can prompt them).

Comment: an you try to hit either ESC key or combination CTRL+ALT+F2 or F5? this should get you to all the messages instead of the dots and you may see the error there.

Comment: Press ESC works i see the services. It stops at "network-dispatcher.service". I will search in this way.